# Webpack: 'require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted' when aliasing require function

Tags: webpack

When sending an expression to Node's `require` function, Webpack has [the ability](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) to analyze the expression, building a runtime table of all of the modules that could be produced. If it can't perform this analysis for some reason, a ([somewhat undocumented](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15970)) warning is sent to the console:
'Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted'

This code triggers the warning:

`global.xyz = require;`

I don't completely understand why. I could understand if `require` was being overwritten, but it is just being aliased. `require` itself can still be statically analyzed. (Even though, in this case, no static analysis needs to happen.)

Is the concern that Webpack won't know to run static analysis on `global.xyz`, if `global.xyz` is sent a runtime expression as an argument?

See [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-sgl4lp?file=src%2Findex.js). Run `npm run build` in the terminal, and scroll up a bit to see the warning.